# Why $\int_a^b f(x) dx=\int_0^\infty g(t) dt \text{ with } t=\frac{x-a}{b-x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm reading Nahin's: *Inside Interesting Integrals*.

> [image]

I don't get why he can write:

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx=\int_0^\infty g(t) dt \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{with } t=\frac{x-a}{b-x}$$

I tried to make an experiment to understand it. I took $\displaystyle \int_2^5 f(x) dx$ and wrote it as $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty g(t) dt$ with $t=\cfrac{x-2}{5-x}$ and tried some values for $t$ On the first integral, I had the domain $[2,5]$, now I have the domain $[0,\infty)$ and this seems to be completely different.

Comment: Let $t=(x-a)/(b-x)$.  Determine $dt/dx$ and consider what happens as $x\to a^+$ and $x\to b^-$.  It should be fairly obvious from there.

Answer (score 2):

Solving for $x$, we get: $$x-a=(b-x)t\\x(t+1)=a+bt\\ x=\frac{a+bt}{t+1}=b-\frac{b-a}{1+t}$$

So $$dx=\frac{(b-a)dt}{(1+t)^2}$$

So let $$g(t)=\frac{(b-a)f\left(\frac{a+bt}{t+1}\right)}{(1+t)^2}$$

Then $$\int_{a}^b f(x)dx = \int_0^\infty g(t)dt$$

The key points is that you obvious have to find the *right* $g(t)$.

Let's take a really simple example, $a=0,b=1, f(x)=1$. Then we get $$g(t)=\frac{1}{(1+t)^2},$$ and we see that:

$$\int_{0}^1 \frac{dt}{(1+t)^2} = 1$$